# generate a.out from lex file using makefile

Tags: c, makefile, lex, flex-lexer

I have `auto.lex` and I want to generate `a.out` of this file  .

I tried -

```
a.out: lex.yy.c
    gcc -c lex.yy.c

lex.yy.c: auto.lex
    flex -c auto.lex
```

but it not worked .

**EDIT:**

changed to  -

```
a.out: lex.yy.c 
    gcc lex.yy.c 
lex.yy.c: auto.lex 
    flex auto.lex
```

and fixed .

Comment: because `-c` tells GCC to compile only and not to link...

Comment: @H2CO3 can you please write the whole correct syntax of this makefile ?

Comment: In **both** the places, delete `-c`  
So it's `gcc lex.yy.c` and `flex auto.lex`

Comment: I replaced the Adobe Flex tag w/ gnu-flex and lex

Comment: @amanmadaan how can I also remove a.out and lex.yy.c each time I execute "make" ?

Comment: @URL87 see my answer. Make automagically removes intermediate files this way.

Comment: Or , to keep it simple, just modify your line 2 as : `gcc lex.yy.c;rm lex.yy.x`  

You can also write a rule in makefile. Please see make man page.

Answer (score 1):

The recommend suffix for lex files is `.l`. GNU make has a builtin rule `.l.c` that creates C code from a lex source. Thus, if you want to create an executable `auto` from `auto.l`, you don't need a makefile at all. Just type `make auto`:

```
$ make auto
lex  -t auto.l > auto.c
cc    -c -o auto.o auto.c
cc   auto.o  -lfl -o auto
rm auto.o auto.c
```