# Trying to create makefile for lex program

Tags: c, lex

Notice, I'm new to **"makefile"**

I have program called "ba.lex" I need to create make file for it.

without the makefile, I first call:

```
flex ba.lex
```

then, I create executable:

```
gcc -o ba lex.yy.c -lfl
```

I will also need to clean the intermediate file: **lex.yy.c**

**How I could put these on a makefile.**

**Update:**
I tried this:

```
flex ba.lex
gcc -o ba lex.yy.c -lfl
```

but I'm getting: `makefile:1: *** commands commence before first target.  Stop.`

Comment: as lex generates `lex.yy.c` you could use it as a target in Makefile. This will not work if you need different lexer.

Comment: Thanks! ... I'm not familer on how to make makefile. Could you please give an example of makefile?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling flex from a makefile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9770170/calling-flex-from-a-makefile)

Comment: These threads [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9770170/calling-flex-from-a-makefile/9770329) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13165681/generate-a-out-from-lex-file-using-makefile) have what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks .... The link there doesn't mention how could I add clean.

Comment: you need a target named `clean` and this target simply removes lex.yy.c with `rm -f lex.yy.c`. Once you understand targets in Makefile you understand the whole magic behind it.

Comment: OK .... I got it ..Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a `Makefile` you don't just write *commands*, that's what shell scripts are for. A `Makefile` has 3 main entities:

- targets
- dependencies
- commands to run

A very simple `Makefile` example can be this one:

```
build: a.out

a.out: a.c
 <TAB> gcc -Wall a.c
```

Here, `build` is a target that depends on `a.out` (which is a file, but we've also created a target with that name). The target `a.out` depends on `a.c` file. What happens when you run `make` is:

```
if (! file_exists(a.out) || last_change(a.out) < last_change(a.c)) then
    execute gcc command
```

In your case, a possible `Makefile` can be:

```
build: ba

ba: lex.yy.c
 <TAB> gcc -o ba lex.yy.c -lfl

lex.yy.c: ba.lex
 <TAB>  flex ba.lex

clean: 
 <TAB> rm lex.yy.c ba *.o
```

Comment: Mostly correct.  Generally, you'd probably avoid depending explicitly on the intermediate file, so you'd have a single rule `ba: ba.lex` with the two commands (`flex` and `gcc`) as actions after it (and possibly `rm -f lex.yy.c` as an extra action).  Also, you should use macros for all commands and most command options: `$(LEX) $(LFLAGS) ba.lex` and `$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ lex.yy.c $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)`, for example.  You can probably use `$<` for `ba.lex`; there isn't a standard macro for `lex.yy.c`, though.

Comment: Oh, and you'd also probably want to use variables like `$<` or `$@` and declare the `clean` target as `.PHONY`. I agree, but I thought that this would have most likely confused the OP.

Comment: There's a fair chance that using the hieroglyph macros (`$<` and `$@`) would confuse.  I might have presented two makefiles — one with hard-coded commands and the other with the macros.  One advantage of using a macro for the `rm` command is that you can avoid having the makefile clean up for you when you want to preserve the `lex.yy.c` file.  I would still probably only present the direct rules.  Also, Make innately knows how to convert a Lex (Flex) file into an object file or into an executable. (Try: `mkdir junk; cd junk; >makefile; >junk.l; make -n junk; make -n junk.o` — WFM on Mac OS X.)